# jQuery stop element from receiving an event

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors, jquery

I have a checkbox on my page. How do I stop it from receiving any event (e.g. touchstart) using jQuery ?

I mean nothing should happen when that checkbox is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable all JavaScript - Handlers on the element:

```
$('#checkbox').unbind();
```

And to prevent the standard-function of the checkbox, you could disable it

```
$('#checkbox').attr('disabled', true);
```

or directly in the Markup:

```
<input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this, but you have to specify the events one by one:

```
$('.selectorToCheckbox').bind('click mouseover', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

The available events are: blur, focus, focusin, focusout, load, resize, scroll, unload, click, dblclick, mousedown, mouseup, mousemove, mouseover, mouseout, mouseenter, mouseleave, change, select, submit, keydown, keypress, keyup, error.

Comment: Why would you specify all of the handlers? jQuery API ->  In the simplest case, with no arguments, .unbind() removes all handlers attached to the elements:

Answer (score 0):

See this: [jQuery unbind()](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)

```
$('#thecheckbox').unbind('click'); // removes all 'click' event handlers from the element
```